# Adding objects to NSMutableArray won't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to make an array(shopImages3) with arrays which hold 3 objects by using a temporary array(tempArray). The big array which contains all the strings to start with is shopImages.

The big array contains 6 strings at this moment. This means it comes 2 times in the

" if((i == 2) || (i == 5) || (i == 8) || (i == 11) || (i == 14) || (i == 18)) "

statement. This works fine. But the NSLogs show the arrays are null.

How can I fill the arrays correctly?

```
2014-08-28 14:01:52.575 Jump Game[3622:60b] this is temp array (null)
2014-08-28 14:01:52.575 Jump Game[3622:60b] this is shopimages array (null)
2014-08-28 14:01:52.576 Jump Game[3622:60b] this is temp array (null)
2014-08-28 14:01:52.576 Jump Game[3622:60b] this is shopimages array (null)
```

THE CODE STARTS FROM HERE

```
@interface ShopCollectionViewController ()
{
    NSArray *shopImages;

    NSMutableArray *shopImages3;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray;
}
```

........

```
for ( int i = 0; i < [shopImages count]; i++)
{

    [tempArray addObject: shopImages[i]];

    if((i == 2) || (i == 5) || (i == 8) || (i == 11) || (i == 14) || (i == 18))
    {
        NSLog(@"this is temp array %@", tempArray);
        [shopImages3 addObject:tempArray];
        NSLog(@"this is shopimages array %@", shopImages3);
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u alloc array or not.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you do not initialise the arrays. In your `init` you need to

```
tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Comment: When I NSLog the *shopImages3 inside the for loop, it shows the correct data. But when I access the array outside the loop it's empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: @ViktorDeBock You say that NSLog for shopImages3 if repeated after the loops shows empty array? How do you initialise shopImages3 and tempArray?

Comment: In the ViewDidLoad method I wrote this: tempArray = [NSMutableArray new]; shopImages3 = [NSMutableArray new];

Comment: It all looks good. Do more investigation - NSLog to be sure that array is empty etc.

Comment: The content of ARRAY is(
        (
    ),
        (
    )
)

So it still show 2 arrays but the content is empty.

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

From your description, it sounds like this would be much better suited for an NSDictionary with the keys being your conditions (i.e. 2,5,7,11,14,18).

As for the null issue, I don't see where your collections are being initialized. You need to that first, unless they are being lazy loaded in the getter if they are properties.

```
NSMutableArray *mAr = [NSMutableArray new];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *mAr = @[obj1,obj2,nil];
```

One last thing for syntactic sugar, you can put those conditions in an `NSSet` and shorten your if conditional.

```
 NSSet *set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], nil]; //etc

 if([set containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the to init you arrays ? Your code should look like this:

```
    tempArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    shopImages3 = [NSMutableArray new];
    shopImages = [NSMutableArray new];

for ( int i = 0; i < [shopImages count]; i++)
{

    [tempArray addObject: shopImages[i]];

    if((i == 2) || (i == 5) || (i == 8) || (i == 11) || (i == 14) || (i == 18))
    {
        NSLog(@"this is temp array %@", tempArray);
        [shopImages3 addObject:tempArray];
        NSLog(@"this is shopimages array %@", shopImages3);
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you First alloc `NSMutableArray` like this

```
tempArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: Do you know, you can write fewer lines of code with `[NSMutableArray new]` :)